# Combination of scope-proxy and parent

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-ioc, spring-io

Hi I have the following short code :

https://github.com/shmuel-buchnik/scope-issue

I am getting the following error :

"Invalid property 'targetBeanName' of bean class [C]: Bean property 'targetBeanName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?"

I will be happy to understand way .

Thanks in advance.

Adding context file to save access to github

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

<bean name="a" class="A">
 <property name="action" ref="c"/>
    </bean>
<bean name="b" class="B" scope="prototype">
    <property name="d" ref="d"/>
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
 </bean>
<bean name="c" class="C" parent="b" scope="prototype">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
</bean>
<bean name="d" class="D"/>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after debugging this is the issue :

When you define a parent in spring that means that you want to inherit parent bean configuration.

When you define scope proxy the proxy bean holds two properties targetBeanName and ProxyTargetClass.

When you inherit  a bean that is a scoped proxy you get those properties as part of merging parent bean configuration .Then your bean try to find a setter for setting property and raise exception.

This means that in our example even if c was not scoped proxy we were still get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a bean definition as a *parent* if the bean definition is configured as an `<aop:scoped-proxy>`.

Thus, just delete the `<aop:scoped-proxy>` declaration for the `b` bean, and it will work.